# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-blade

I got the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\enginepoker2\storage\framework\views\10cbbd076bede57a96e59c43af0e1b9e022b4a69.php on line 115

The query builder:

```
$statsMoneyInPlay = DB::table('enginepoker_log.poker')
    ->select(
        DB::raw("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100) as timestamp"),
        DB::raw("SUM(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay")
    )
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE(ts)"))
    ->orderByRaw("DATE(ts)")
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

The Blade that gets the error:

```
@php
    foreach ($statsMoneyInPlay as $key => $value) {
        echo "[".$value[0].", ".$value[1]."],";
    }
@endphp
```

Comment: whats the output when you use dd($statsMoneyInPlay); in your controller after that query builder ?

Comment: this is the output https://drive.google.com/open?id=155HDjiiQUH9SjmPdNBb2sOA-xONX_moH

Comment: please try to convert this object to array as, $statsMoneyInPlay = (array) $statsMoneyInPlay;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is born from a misuse of the array itself. Try the following:

```
foreach($statsMoneyInPlay as $stat) {
  echo "[" . $stat['timestamp'] . ", " . $stat['moneyInPlay'] . "]";
}
```

**EDIT**:
The `$statsMoneyInPlay` is an array of objects, so the proper way to access it would be:

```
foreach($statsMoneyInPlay as $stat) {
  echo "[" . $stat->timestamp . ", " . $stat->moneyInPlay . "]";
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadRomiMuhtarom fixed, proper credit should be given to the answer above by lagbox

Comment: ok, I still get an error this is the error said Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Answer (score 4):

That DB query returns a `Collection` of `stdClass` objects. It does not return a `Collection` of arrays. Calling `toArray` on that `Collection` will give you an array of `stdClass` objects.

```
@foreach ($statsMoneyInPlay as $value)
    [ {{ $value->timestamp }}, {{ $value->moneyInPlay }} ],
@endforeach
```